# Is RefCell an appropriate workaround to borrow two mutable elements from a vector?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, refcell

Consider this toy example of "fighting" two random "players":

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Player {
    name: String,
    health: i32,
    attack: i32,
}

fn fight(player_a: &mut Player, player_b: &mut Player) {
    player_a.health -= player_b.attack;
    player_b.health -= player_a.attack;
}

fn main() {
    // Create Vector of 100 new players
    let players: Vec<Player> = vec![
        Player {
            name: String::new(),
            health: 100,
            attack: 5,
        };
        100
    ];

    // Pick two "random" indices
    let i1 = 19;
    let i2 = 30;

    fight(&mut players[i1], &mut players[i2]); // Error!
}
```

This code will not work as the `fight` function takes two mutable references to elements of the same `players` vector.

My ugly workaround currently looks like the following, using `RefCell`:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

let mut players: Vec<RefCell<Player>> = vec![];
for _ in 0..100 {
    players.push(RefCell::new(Player {
        name: String::new(),
        health: 100,
        attack: 5,
    }));
}

fight(&mut players[i1].borrow_mut(), &mut players[i2].borrow_mut());
```

I'd like to know if there's a more efficient way of doing this to avoid the extra overhead of `RefCell`? Can I leverage `split_at_mut` somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `fight` method like next:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Player {
    name: String,
    health: i32,
    attack: i32,
}

fn fight(players: &mut [Player], player1_index: usize, player2_index: usize) {
    players[player1_index].health -= players[player2_index].attack;
    players[player2_index].health -= players[player1_index].attack;
}

fn main() {
    // Create Vector of 100 new players
    let mut players: Vec<Player> = vec![
        Player {
            name: String::new(),
            health: 100,
            attack: 5,
        };
        100
    ];

    // Pick two "random" indices
    let i1 = 19;
    let i2 = 30;

    fight(&mut players, i1, i2);
}
```

Or you can try to workaround this issue with `Option`:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Player {
    name: String,
    health: i32,
    attack: i32,
}

fn fight(player_a: &mut Player, player_b: &mut Player) {
    player_a.health -= player_b.attack;
    player_b.health -= player_a.attack;
}

fn main() {
    // Create Vector of 100 new players
    let mut players: Vec<Option<Player>> = vec![
        Some(Player {
            name: String::new(),
            health: 100,
            attack: 5,
        });
        100
    ];

    // Pick two "random" indices
    let i1 = 19;
    let i2 = 30;

    let mut player1 = players[i1].take().unwrap();
    let mut player2 = players[i2].take().unwrap();
    fight(&mut player1, &mut player2);
    players[i1].replace(player1);
    players[i2].replace(player2);
}
```

Or if you really need 100% performance, you can try to dig deeper into unsafe raw pointers. But you should think twice.

Comment: I've done some benchmarking and all 3 proposed solutions so far are around twice as fast as the original RefCell workaround. Your first suggestion of modifying the `fight` function is the fastest and the simplest, and looks like the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It’s possible to use `split_at_mut` to borrow both exclusively:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Player {
    name: String,
    health: i32,
    attack: i32,
}

fn fight(player_a: &mut Player, player_b: &mut Player) {
    player_a.health -= player_b.attack;
    player_b.health -= player_a.attack;
}

fn get2<T>(arr: &mut [T], a: usize, b: usize) -> (&mut T, &mut T) {
    use std::cmp::Ordering;

    let (sw, a, b) = match Ord::cmp(&a, &b) {
        Ordering::Less => (false, a, b),
        Ordering::Greater => (true, b, a),
        Ordering::Equal =>
            panic!("attempted to exclusive-borrow one element twice"),
    };
    
    let (arr0, arr1) = arr.split_at_mut(a + 1);
    let (ea, eb) = (&mut arr0[a], &mut arr1[b - (a + 1)]);

    if sw {
        (eb, ea)
    } else {
        (ea, eb)
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Create Vector of 100 new players
    let mut players: Vec<Player> = vec![
        Player {
            name: String::new(),
            health: 100,
            attack: 5,
        };
        100
    ];

    // Pick two "random" indices
    let i1 = 19;
    let i2 = 30;
    
    let (p1, p2) = get2(&mut players, i1, i2);

    println!("{} ({} HP) vs {} ({} HP)",
        p1.attack, p1.health, p2.attack, p2.health);
    fight(p1, p2);
    println!("{} ({} HP) vs {} ({} HP)",
        p1.attack, p1.health, p2.attack, p2.health);
}
```